# Linphone, is it possible to change recordings location?

Tags: software-recommendation, audio-recording, sip, linphone

I need to record some phone calls, therefore I installed Linphone (on Ubuntu 20.04), which has this feature. However, I don't see any option in the preferences to select the location where the program stores recordings. It puts them into `~/Music`. I'd rather use a different location, because this folder is pretty crowded in my system and I don't want to mix phone call recordings with actual music in my music players. Is there any way to change this?

Or can anybody recommend another SIP phone application that can record calls and has a configurable recordings location? I tried also Twinkle, but it seems there's no call recording feature in this program.